# Can't connect bot to discord

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I was learning to code a discord bot using python.
Recently created a bot and successfully added it to my discord server.
I installed discord.py and python-dotenv using pip.
got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jjjf9\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 261, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "C:\Users\jjjf9\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 225, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 UNAUTHORIZED (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized       

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:/discord/bot.py", line 15, in <module>
    client.run(token)
  File "C:\Users\jjjf9\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 640, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\jjjf9\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 621, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jjjf9\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 584, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\jjjf9\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 442, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\jjjf9\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 265, in static_login
    raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x000001C7B373F700>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__ 
    self.close()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close   
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 715, in call_soon   
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 508, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

the code:
bot.py

```
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
token = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

client.run(token)
```

.env

```
DISCORD_TOKEN={XXXXXXXXXXXX}
```

Comment: The problem might be that you use DISCORD_TOKEN={XXXXX} instead of DISCORD_TOKEN=XXXXX

Comment: Tried removing brackets got the same error.
Also tried adding 'token' instead of brackets and got
.
.
line 228, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 429 TOO MANY REQUESTS (error code: 0): You are being rate 
limited.

Comment: The too many requests error can indicate that you use the wrong token. After a few tries discord will block the request. Have you tried doing the following: print(token) do you see your token?

Comment: where u able to resolve this? having the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing

`token= "yourtokenhere"`

instead of

`token = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')`

to test if your os.getenv is retrieving your token properly. If it works you will know that os.getenv is not working properly. If it gives the same error then you have an invalid token.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like an invalid token.

Try removing the curly braces from your token in your .env file.

Comment: Tried removing brackets got the same error.
Also tried adding 'token' instead of brackets and got
.
.
line 228, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 429 TOO MANY REQUESTS (error code: 0): You are being rate 
limited.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue until I did the following:

Change line 6 from

```
load_dotenv()
```

to

```
load_donenv('.env.txt')
```